# Java - 'Name clash' and 'constructor undefined' error when overriding inner class that inherits a generic from the outer class

Tags: java, eclipse, name-clash

I recently upgraded the eclipse and java version in a project and some errors occured.
I tried to reproduce and found out that the following setup lead to the errors in in Eclipse Oxigen.3a (4.7.3a) using Java 1.8, while the same works with eclipse 3.7.2 and Java 1.7

TestSomeObject.java:

```
package a;
public class TestSomeObject
{
}
```

TestGeneric.java:

```
package a;
public class TestGeneric<T>
{
  T element;

  protected class InnerGeneric
  {
     T innerElement;

     public InnerGeneric() { }
  }
}
```

TestA.java:

```
package a;

public class TestA extends TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>
{
  public TestA(String a, String b) {}

  public InnerA someMethod(String some, InnerGeneric inner)
  {
     return new InnerA(some, inner);
  }

  protected class InnerA
  {
     public InnerA(String a, InnerGeneric b) {  }
  }
}
```

TestB.java

```
package a;
import a.TestA;

public class TestB extends TestA
{
  public TestB(String a, String b){
     super(a,b);
  }

  public InnerA someMethod(String some, InnerGeneric inner)
  {
     return new InnerB(some, inner);
  }

  protected class InnerB extends InnerA
  {
     public InnerB(String a, InnerGeneric b)
     {
        super(a, b);
     }
  }
}
```

In class Test B, I get the following compilation errors:

1. someMethod: `Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
   Name clash: The method someMethod(String, TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>.InnerGeneric) of type TestB has the same erasure as someMethod(String, TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>.InnerGeneric) of type TestA but does not override it   TestB.java      line 13 Java Problem`
2. when calling super(a,b): `Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
   The constructor TestA.InnerA(String, TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>.InnerGeneric) is undefined TestB.java      line 22`enter code here`Java Problem`

In eclipse Version: 3.7.2 and Java 1.7, this works.

Why is that? What can I do to clear the errors?

Comment: Did you include all the relevant code? The error message mentions `TestSomeObject`, but you did not show where you use that class.

Comment: Sorry, it is the class used for the generic.

Comment: I jsut copied all the code you posted with the proper packages and such and it doesn't compile because of visibility problems in class `TestB`. `InnerA` and `InnerGeneric` are not visible. Also you should add the code you use for testing

Comment: the package is not relevant ... you can change package b to package a. I just didn't want to post my internal packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, to more precisely define the InnerGeneric class in the method signature:

TestB.java:

```
package a;

public class TestB extends TestA
{
  public TestB(String a, String b){
     super(a,b);
  }

  public InnerA someMethod(String some, TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>.InnerGeneric inner)
  {
     return new InnerB(some, inner);
  }

  protected class InnerB extends InnerA
  {
     public InnerB(String a, TestGeneric<TestSomeObject>.InnerGeneric b)
     {
        super(a, b);
     }
  }
}
```